# Child table with keys

Tags: c, lua

good day
i need return structure from C code to Lua.
My structure has named fields, one of them is array of other named structure:

```
{
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": [
        {"field1": 11, "field2": 12},
        {"field1": 21, "field2": 22}
    ],
    "baz": 3
}
```

i wrote this code:

```
lua_createtable(L, 0, 3); //0 indexed items, 3 keyed items

lua_pushnumber(L, 1);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "foo"); //root.foo = 1;

lua_createtable(L, 2, 0); //child table for bar field with 2 indexed items and 0 keyed

lua_pushnumber(L, 1); // set current item index to 1

lua_createtable(L, 0, 2); // child table with 2 keyed items

lua_pushnumber(L, 11);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "field1"); //root.bar[0].field1 = 11;

lua_pushnumber(L, 12);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "field2"); //root.bar[0].field2 = 12;

lua_settable(L, -2); //set root.bar[0]

lua_pushnumber(L, -2); //set current item index to 2

lua_createtable(L, 0, 2); //table for second bar items with 2 keys

lua_pushnumber(L, 21);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "field1"); //root.bar[1].field1 = 21;

lua_pushnumber(L, 22);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "field2"); //root.bar[1].field2 = 22;

lua_settable(L, -2); //set root.bar[1]
lua_setfield(L, -2, "bar"); //set root.bar

lua_pushnumber(L, 3);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "baz"); //root.baz = 3;
```

but it failed with exception. previous i try to do this without lua_settable and call lua_setfield(L, -2, "bar") for child table after lua_createtalbe(L, 2, 0) but then i receive structure with follow fields:

```
root.field1 = 21
root.field2 = 22
root.baz = 3
```

how can i achieve target structure?

Comment: Replace `lua_settable(L, -2); //set root.bar[0]` with `lua_settable(L, -3);`

Comment: Replace `lua_pushnumber(L, -2); //set current item index to 2` with `lua_pushnumber(L, 2);`